# Get list based on FromIndex to EndIndex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing

data array variable contains big number of data, And i have some of StartIndex and EndIndex, I need only those data which are in between startIndex and EndEndex.

Is there any method which can help to get data in from start index to EndEndex without using for loop.

StartIndex and EndIndex are dynamic which can change any time while running web page.

```js
var data=[
   {
    "ID": "1783603",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783604",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783605",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783606",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783607",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783608",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783609",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783610",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   },
   {
    "ID": "1783611",
    "LongDescription": "this is long desc.",
    "ShortDescription": "This is long desc",
    "Name": "Name Field"
   }
  ]
console.log(data)

var FromIndex=2;
var EndIndex=5;
var ResultArray=[];

for(var i=FromIndex;i<=EndIndex;i++){
  ResultArray.push(data[i])
}

console.log(ResultArray)
```

Comment: use `Array.filter()` to accomplish what you need

Comment: You can user array.slice(start, end) to break the array

Comment: working with array.slice(start, end)

Answer (score 1):

Use slice method of an array. [An Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_slice_array)